# Save Excel Sheet as CSV in UTF-8 Using VBA

Tags: vba, csv, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm working on the following macro in excel, which loops through all of the Worksheets in a Workbook and saves each to its own .csv file. The issue is that I need it to save as a .csv encoded with UTF-8. I read that Excel's default encoding for .csv is ANSI, which won't work for me because I have some files with special characters in them. Does anyone know how I can go about this?

The macro:

```
Public Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()

Dim wsExport As Worksheet
Dim wbkExport As Workbook

For Each wsExport In Worksheets
wsExport.Select
nm = wsExport.Name
If Not IsActiveSheetEmpty() Then
    ActiveSheet.SaveAs fileName:="H:\CSV_Split_Exports\" & nm, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

Next wsExport

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The "easy way" is to save as "Unicode Text." This will be UTF-16, **tab** delimited format, rather than comma delimited.

Most software import processes allows you to specify the delimiter when importing the data, but if your particular application does not, you can post-process the file with a find+replace to change the tab to a comma.

Comment: Is there a "hard way?" The import software I'm using doesn't allow me to select my delimiter and the whole goal of me writing this macro was to avoid things like individual post-processing. I don't mind trying to implement a more complex macro if it gets me where I need to go.

Comment: you can post-process the file in VBA after you export it: open it, read lines, process the tabs, write to new file. Need to use unicode-safe string functions.

Comment: Oh, okay. I understand what you're saying. Is there any way you could help me with the VBA for that?  I'm just learning how to use it and I feel like that goes a bit over my head as of now.

Comment: You need to open two files, one to read, one to write. You then read a line to a string variable, use `replace()` on the variable, then write to the second file. You would use something like a "while not end-of file loop". Check the VBA documentation also, but here is a VB *Script* version of something without the loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410334/filesystemobject-reading-unicode-files

Comment: You will find a lot of simple input/output text file examples, some even on MSDN. It isn't very complicated. Once you get something that doesn't work (!), if you get stuck, check out stackoverflow. The best way is to save an example file, and then play with it as a function with 2 parameters (infile, outfile), then once you get that done, insert the call to the function into the loop you posted above, immediately before your `Next wsExport`